# Speed up MySQL query made in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Say, i have a table a given [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/14191/1). The table has the following structure (day of test, name of student, and marks obtained)

```
D       NAME    MARKS
2001-01-01  a   1
2001-01-04  a   4
2001-01-06  a   3
2001-01-08  a   3
2001-01-01  b   1
2001-01-10  b   15
2001-01-01  c   1
2001-01-06  c   2
2001-01-08  c   5
2001-01-10  c   7
```

I'd like to update the table by give 0 marks to those students who do not have an entry for each test. The update table should look like [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8e1a4)

```
D   NAME    MARKS
2001-01-01  a   1
2001-01-02  a   0
2001-01-04  a   4
2001-01-06  a   3
2001-01-08  a   3
2001-01-02  a   0
2001-01-01  b   1
2001-01-02  b   0
2001-01-04  b   0
2001-01-06  b   0
2001-01-08  b   0
2001-01-10  b   15
2001-01-01  c   1
2001-01-02  c   2
2001-01-04  c   0
2001-01-06  c   0
2001-01-08  c   5
2001-01-10  c   7
```

So far, the only solution(very very slow query) i can figure out is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(D) FROM tableA;
SELECT DISTINCT(NAME) FROM tableA;
```

Using PHP, a sql query is made inside a nested loop

```
INSERT IGNORE (D,NAME,MARKS)($D,$NAME,0);
```

However, the whole code takes too much time (in minutes) as there are more than 50k rows.

Any better suggestions?

Comment: generate all those queries to STDOUT and pipe them into `mysql` on the commmandline. tell mysql to lock the table for exclusive access so that it can be run in a single transaction.

Comment: @hakre, i didnt understand anything :| i'm so sorry :( Can u please explain a in simple words...

Comment: See this for more info: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html - Like output created by this program that can be read back in (it's explained there how), you can create your INSERT queries with your PHP script and then run them as if they were a dump.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possibly do a cross join of the possible dates and possible names and left join that against the current results:-

```
INSERT INTO A (D, name, marks)
SELECT Dates.D, Names.name, 0
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT D FROM A) Dates
CROSS JOIN  (SELECT DISTINCT name FROM A) Names
LEFT OUTER JOIN A
ON Dates.D = A.D AND Names.name = A.name
WHERE A.name IS NULL
```

Note this does assume that at least one person has a mark for each day.

It would be better if you had a table of names and a table of dates, and just used the ids of these rows in the table A

If you want to do this for a range of dates, even if nobody got a mark that day:-

```
INSERT INTO A (D, name, marks)
SELECT Dates.aDate, Names.name, 0
FROM 
(
    SELECT DATE_ADD('2001-01-01', INTERVAL units.i + tens.i * 10 + hundreds.i * 100 DAY) AS aDate
    FROM (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) units
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) tens
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) hundreds
    HAVING aDate BETWEEN '2001-01-01' AND '2001-12-30'
) Dates
CROSS JOIN  
(
    SELECT DISTINCT name 
    FROM A
) Names
LEFT OUTER JOIN A
ON Dates.aDate = A.D AND Names.name = A.name
WHERE A.name IS NULL
```

Comment: hmmm, ya, nice idea, but the code above didnt work, i'll work on it :)

Comment: oops! sorry! it works perfect!! i forgot to ORDER BY. Its working perfect :)

Comment: Fair enough. Added an edit if you want to add marks for days within a range of dates (up to 1000 days in the example) when nobody had a mark

Comment: Well, i've another table but this time it has 53k rows, ~1300 names, 365 days. when i try to execute the query in godaddy server, it never works (error: #2006 - MySQL server has gone away). So, is there any lighter query?

Comment: Best thing is to redesign the database design. Have a users table (so ~1300 rows on it) and use the index from that in your current table.  Join that against you existing table which saves the subselect to get the list of names. Beyond that make very sure it is using indexes.

Comment: Actually, i cant redesign the db as the db is used by many other queries from other projects (have to rewrite the whole projects). So, i've created all the sub SELECT into separate tables (temporary), indexed. And now its working fasts (takes just a few seconds) :)